# PyQt5 interface immediately closes after launch

Tags: python, class, interface, pyqt5, shutdown

I am trying to create an interface for my market program with a refresh button in it. The problem is that the window closes almost immediately after it opens. I checked some solutions but I couldn't do anything because I am not sure if the problem is about the button or class system since I am not experienced with using the classes.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore

class Pencere(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()
    
    
    def  init_ui(self):

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        window.setWindowTitle("Markets")
        
        #window.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        
        window.setGeometry(670,300,400,430)
        
        ####################################################    VERİLERİ ALMA
        
        self.url = "https://www.doviz.com//"

        self.response = requests.get(self.url)

        self.html_content = (self.response).content

        self.soup = BeautifulSoup((self.html_content),"html.parser")

        self.titles1 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"USD"})
        self.titles2 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"EUR"})
        self.titles3 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"bitcoin"})
        self.titles4 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"XU100"})    
        self.titles1 = self.titles1.text
        self.titles2 = self.titles2.text
        self.titles3 = self.titles3.text
        self.titles4 = self.titles4.text
        
        ####################################################    RESİMLERİ KOYMA
        
        self.image1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window) 
        self.image1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("jdollar.png"))
        self.image1.move(50,50)
        
        self.image2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window) 
        self.image2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("jeuro.png"))
        self.image2.move(50,120)
        
        self.image3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window) 
        self.image3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("jbtc.png"))
        self.image3.move(50,190)
        
        self.image4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window) 
        self.image4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("jbist.png"))
        self.image4.move(58,260)
        
        ####################################################    SAYILARI YAZDIRMA
        
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
        self.text1.setText(self.titles1)    
        self.text1.move(125,68)

        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
        self.text2.setText(self.titles2)    
        self.text2.move(125,138)

        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
        self.text3.setText(self.titles3)    
        self.text3.move(125,278)
        
        self.text4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
        self.text4.setText(self.titles4)    
        self.text4.move(125,208)

        ####################################################    BUTONLARI OLUŞTURMA

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
        self.button1.setText("Refresh")
        self.button1.move(150,330)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.__init__)
        
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
        self.button2.setText("Exit")
        self.button2.move(150,360)
        
        ####################################################    EKRANI AÇMA
        
        self.show()
    
    def stats(self):
        
        self.url = "https://www.doviz.com//"

        self.response = requests.get(self.url)

        self.html_content = (self.response).content

        self.soup = BeautifulSoup((self.html_content),"html.parser")

        self.titles1 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"USD"})
        self.titles2 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"EUR"})
        self.titles3 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"bitcoin"})
        self.titles4 = self.soup.find("span",{"data-socket-key":"XU100"})    
        self.titles1 = self.titles1.text
        self.titles2 = self.titles2.text
        self.titles3 = self.titles3.text
        self.titles4 = self.titles4.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Pencere()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Remove the `app = ...` in `init_ui` and also the button connection to `self.__init__` which is not only pointless but also terribly **wrong**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove
**app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)** part in

```
def  init_ui(self):

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

you are using two QApplications. Although you can use only one.